# Why does my installer always prompt for reboot

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I only want to reboot when uninstalling. This is a fragment from my WiX file:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  ...
  <Custom Action="CleanRegistry" Sequence="7100">REMOVE~="ALL" AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
  <ScheduleReboot Sequence="7200">REMOVE~="ALL" AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</ScheduleReboot>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Running the generated MSI produces the following log:

```
MSI (s) (48:7C) [10:19:29:951]: Skipping action: CleanRegistry (condition is false)
MSI (s) (48:7C) [10:19:29:951]: Doing action: ScheduleReboot
```

How is it possible that the same condition evaluates to False then True? Does ScheduleReboot ever ignore its condition?

Edit: I am also trying to use the condition REBOOT~="Force" to conditionally execute a command when a reboot has been requested by my customaction. This condition is never evaluating to true and my command is not being run. The property is being set by a call to MsiSetProperty from a custom action. Either this custom action is not working or I have made a mistake in my condition! Any suggestions?

Comment: There might be another action in your MSI triggering ScheduleReboot. Have you tried searching for it using Orca?

Comment: My WiX file only has a single ScheduleReboot action and the install log shows it getting executed right after my customaction with the same condition was skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the original code was failing but I have ended up settling on the following which only does a reboot on upgrade or uninstall.

```
<ScheduleReboot Sequence="7200">REMOVE~="ALL"</ScheduleReboot>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some action might be setting the REBOOT property. You should be able to see that in the log. The most common reason is probably files in use.

Comment: I have a custom action which I am expecting to set REBOOT=FORCE. Will this cause ScheduleReboot to ignore its condition?

Comment: I don't the know the exact implementation details, but my guess is that all ScheduleReboot does is to set REBOOT=FORCE. You've essentially done the same without it.

Comment: That sounds as expected but still begs the question why the log shows that the ScheduleReboot action is executed.

Comment: Is it possible that a previous action changes the value of REMOVE?

Comment: The WiX fragment I posted does not hide any intermediate actions. CleanRegistry is skipped and then ScheduleReboot is called and the condition evaluates to true!